# Current user shows nil after sign in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I want to get current logged in user object with Devise's accessor method `current_user` in my home controller. But unfortunately I cannot able to access the current_user, Can anyone please help me out here. Please check my model and controller here.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :name, :subdomain, :presence => true
  validates :email, :subdomain, :uniqueness => true

  has_one :page, :dependent => :destroy

  def self.select_user_for_page(user)
    if user
      user.user_id ? User.find(user.user_id) : user
    end
  end
end
```

home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @page = User.select_user_for_page(current_user).try(:page)
    render :layout => "edit"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `authenticate_user` method as before filter like:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

...
end
```

and check current_user.

Comment: still getting current_user nil after using `before_action :authenticate_user!`

Comment: then add `binding.pry` in controller action and check current_user

Comment: ```[1] pry(#<HomeController>)> current_user
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT
 1
=> nil``` still getting nil

Comment: do you have user in table?

Comment: add application.rb config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

Comment: also check user_signed_in? on binding.pry

Comment: have you properly signed in with email and password?

Comment: Yep, I have signed in with email and password, `user_signed_in?` => false

Comment: you are not signed in beacuse `user_signed_in` is false

Comment: have you confirmed your user also?

Comment: try to signup with new email, confirm it then try signin

Comment: have you got email regarding confirmation?

Comment: Ya, I am getting email regarding confirmation. After confirmation only user able to login. For both signup and signin the `current_user` is nil. Is there any other way to get current user. I have tried with custom function in application_controller still the result is same.
```def current_user  @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])   end```